# SSIS Package Error: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I am getting below exception while executing package with "Script Task" from my .NET application, if I remove script task from package then it's running fine.

> To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Script Task of Integration Services or higher.

When I am executing package with script task from SSDT 2015 then it works fine as expected. Also, checked service "SQL Server Integration Services 11.0" which is also running fine.

I have installed following:

1. SQL SERVER 2012 with all the features
2. SSDT 2015 for developing packages (deployment target version is selected to SQL SERVER 2012)
3. Visual Studio 2017 for calling the Package from my application

I think it's problem of version but I am not able to find the solution yet.

Any help would be great!!

Comment: When open script task in SSDT, there is a references folder in the solution explorer. Rreferences - Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS. Can you give a try to get/add higher version of one or both dlls? I guess one or both of them are not compatible to VS 2017 based on the error message you got.